# 2002 Camry Sludge issues

Tags: toyota, camry, sludge

2002 Camry drives well with 150k on the original engine.
Its my daughters car and she is due to make a big trip so I am giving it the dad DIY once over.
Found a very clogged PCV, and when I removed the oil fill cap, found thick chunky sludge.  Confirmed that it was in fact sludge with my auto parts friends.
Looking for some suggestions as how to proceed with the sludge issue...
Do I use an engine cleaner?
Seafoam ?
Kerosene?
Most everything else with the car is in solid shape, dont want to scrap it.
Anyone with experience please reply.
FYI, this is my first post on this site, Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome.   Which engine? 4 or 6 cylinder?   Sludge severity varies from light that can be managed with extra oil changes to severe requiring more invasive measures.  The best way to find out is to remove a valve cover and  see how much sludge is present. If you can,  post a picture of the underside of the cover and the valve train area.

Comment: It's the 1MZ-FE 6 cylinder.

Comment: You can see sludge under the oil fill cap.

Comment: Some sludge on, or near the cap is not uncommon and unfortunately does not predict the amount of sludge that may be found farther in. Also, excess sludge is not common on this engine as it was on its predecessor. The most common predictor of this issue is very short trip driving in cool damp climates.